# FTPES: Does it encrypt data?

Tags: ftp, sftp, ftps

I'm currently connected to my FTP server using [FTPES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS).

I'm wondering: when I connect to the FTP server is the data transferred between my PC and the server encrypted? From the log I can see it is authenticated.

Here is my server log. From it, can I tell if it was encrypted?:

```
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    CWD MyS03
Response:   250 CWD command successful
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/MyFiles" is the current directory
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (37,58,52,72,195,33).
Command:    MLSD
Response:   150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for MLSD
Response:   226 Transfer complete
Status: Directory listing successful
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  File transfer failed after transferring 155,893,760 bytes in 247 seconds
Status: Resolving address of 192.168.10.111
Status: Connecting to 11.135.156.147:21210...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 (vsFTPd 2.3.5)
Command:    AUTH TLS
Response:   234 Proceed with negotiation.
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Command:    USER darklord
Status: TLS/SSL connection established.
Response:   331 Please specify the password.
Command:    PASS ********
Response:   230 Login successful.
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 Always in UTF8 mode.
Command:    PBSZ 0
Response:   200 PBSZ set to 0.
Command:    PROT P
Response:   200 PROT now Private.
Status: Connected
Status: Starting download of /test.mov
Command:    CWD /rtorrent/data
Response:   250 Directory successfully changed.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (5,135,156,147,78,83).
Command:    REST 155893760
Response:   350 Restart position accepted (55893760).
Command:    RETR test.mov
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for test.mov (197992856 bytes).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the FTPS (FTPES) does not necessarily mean that data is encrypted. Though typically it is encrypted (as is in this particular instance).

Your client requested *Private* Data Channel Protection Level using the `PROT P` command. The *Private* level means that the data will be *integrity and confidentiality protected*.

As the server acknowledged the request (the response `200 PROT now Private`), the data are encrypted (= confidentiality protection).

For details see the [RFC 2228](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2228).